# Discord js Voice | How to use AudioResource

Tags: discord.js, voice

I'm trying to create an `AudioResource` according to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/main/class/AudioResource), but I don't know what to fill in edges and streams. I only have `yt(youtube-url)` from `ytdl-core`. Please advise what information is required. I try create Audio Resource via `new Voice.AudioResource` on way documentation. I know about `createAudioResource`, but is there any possibility to do it differently?

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if(message.content == '!test'){
        
        const VoiceConnection = new Voice.VoiceConnection({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            selfDeaf: true,
        }, {
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            debug: true
        })

        VoiceConnection.rejoin()

        const Player = new Voice.AudioPlayer()
        const Resource = new Voice.AudioResource([], [yt(youtube-url)]) // error

        VoiceConnection.subscribe(Player)

        Player.play(Resource)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

createAudioPlayer isn't the most stable audio player but it is the only one fully supported by the Discord.js Developers at this time. It should be a good idea using the way they support.
Take some minutes to read this [document](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-player.html#audio-player) it is very important.

I think you want something like this:

```
audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource(stream))
```

I did not test this code but I think it works:

```
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

const { createAudioPlayer } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const player = createAudioPlayer();

const songURL= 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak5oJcXSnQw'

const stream = ytdl(songURL, {filter: 'audioonly'});

player.play(createAudioResource(stream));
```